# Add class to DIV if checkbox is checked onload

Tags: checkbox, mootools, addclass

I need help with a script to add an "active" class to a div when a hidden checkbox is checked. This all happening within a somewhat complex form that can be saved and later edited. Here's the process:

I have a series of hidden checkboxes that are checked when a visible DIV is clicked. Thanks to a few people, especially Dimitar Christoff from previous posts here, I have a few simple scripts that handle everything:

1. A person clicks on a div:

   `<div class="thumb left prodata" data-id="7">` yadda yadda `</div>`
2. An active class is added to the div:

   ```
     $$('.thumb').addEvent('click', function(){
       this.toggleClass('tactive');
     });
   ```
3. The corresponding checkbox is checked:

   ```
   document.getElements("a.add_app").addEvents({
   click: function(e) {
       if (e.target.get("tag") != 'input') {
            var checkbox = document.id("field_select_p" + this.get("data-id"));
            checkbox.set("checked", !checkbox.get("checked"));
       }
   }
   ```

   });

Now, I need a fourth ( and final ) function to complete the project (using mootools or just plain javascript, no jQuery). When the form is loaded after being saved, I need a way to add the active class back to the corresponding div. Basically reverse the process. I AM trying to figure it out myself, and would love to post an idea but anything I've tried is, well, bad. I thought I'd at least get this question posted while I work on it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, in case anyone is interested, here is the final solution. What this does is: Create a click event for a DIV class to toggle an active class onclick, and also correlates each DIV to a checkbox using a data-id="X" that = the checkbox ID. Finally, if the form is reloaded ( in this case the form can be saved and edited later ) the final piece of javascript then sees what checkboxes are checked on page load and triggers the active class for the DIV.

To see it all in action, check it out here: https://www.worklabs.ca/2/add-new/add-new?itemetype=website ( script is currently working on the third tab, CHOOSE STYLE ). You won't be able to save/edit it unless you're a member however, but it works:) You can unhide the checkboxes using firebug and toggle the checkboxes yourself to see.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

// apply the psuedo event to some elements
$$('.thumb').addEvent('click', function() {
    this.toggleClass('tactive');
});

$$('.cbox').addEvent('click', function() {
   var checkboxes= $$('.cbox');

       for(i=1; i<=checkboxes.length; i++){
               if(checkboxes[i-1].checked){
               if($('c_'+checkboxes[i-1].id))
                       $('c_'+checkboxes[i-1].id).set("class", "thumb tactive");
               }
       else{
               if($('c_'+checkboxes[i-1].id))
                       $('c_'+checkboxes[i-1].id).set("class", "thumb");
               }
       }
});

// Add the active class to the corresponding div when a checkbox is checked onLoad... basic idea:
var checkboxes= $$('.cbox');

for(i=1; i<=checkboxes.length; i++){
    if(checkboxes[i-1].checked){
       $('c_field_tmp_'+i).set("class", "thumb tactive");
    }
}

document.getElements("div.thumb").addEvents({
      click: function(e) {
        if (e.target.get("tag") != 'input') {
          var checkbox = document.id("field_tmp_" + this.get("data-id"));
          checkbox.set("checked", !checkbox.get("checked"));
        }
      }
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEvents({
  load: function(){
    if (checkbox.checked){
      document.getElements('.thumb').fireEvent('click');
    }
  }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vCH9n/

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that I can "firevent" the click function that's already there. That seems like a good idea, but I'm not sure how to fire that event for the right DIV / checkbox ID pairs. IE: The div with data-id="7" correlates to the checkbox field_select_p_7, so how do I tell the div with data-id="7" to add a class to that div? Can it be done as is, or do I need to add unique ID's to all of my divs? That's the part I can't figure out.

Comment: Okay I've created a jsFiddle with the working code and then started working on a way to iterate through the checkboxes. How to tell the corresponding div's of checked boxes to be active, still can't figure out: http://jsfiddle.net/marcodeluca/A6PR8/29/